# how to put an onclick listener inside of a Service

Tags: android, service, onclick, onclicklistener, android-notifications

i tried to put this `onClick` Listener inside of a Service to register clicks from a `button` in a custom `xml` view that is inside of a notification bar.   But the `onClickListener` gets complier error.  Does anyone know why the compile error is there?

```
   RemoteViews remoteviews = new RemoteViews("com.example.test", R.layout.custom_notifications);

     NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AudioService.this)
               .setContent(remoteviews)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!")
                .setOngoing(true);



     remoteviews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(AudioViewer.this, "play button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Error from the complier is shown as in the below image:

[image]

Comment: What compiler error do you see?

Comment: only one,  a red underline under setOnClickListener.  using eclipse

Comment: which error it is showing can you tell error name or any information....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `setOnClickPendingIntent` instead. The RemoteViews class doesn't have the `setOnClickListener` method defined.

You need to do something like this:

```
this.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Toast.makeText(AudioViewer.this,
                        "play button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new IntentFilter("MyRemoteViewsBroadcast"));
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                       new Intent("MyRemoteViewsBroadcast"), 0);
remoteviews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.layout.custom_notifications, pi);
```

Comment: where do i put the intent that is being sent from the button that is being clicked?   do I make a new activity and setContentview(R.layout.custom_notifications)  and send the intent from there to the service that contains the media player?

Comment: Not sure I understand you...what behavior are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: you explained why the onclick listerner does not work. now i understand that part.   what i am trying to do now is find were to put the code you mentioned, does that go inside of the Service class that has the Media player inside of it?   and the name of the ImageButton is not mentioned in the code.  like if you have the ImageButton called button that is what is clicked on.  but how does it know which button was clicked.  if there is pause, stop and play in the custom xml view?

Comment: You put my code in place of where your `remoteviews.setOnClickListener` was. If you want to set the onClick pending intent for a button with the ID `play_button`, for instance, you would write `remoteviews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.play_button, pi)` instead of `remoteviews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.layout.custom_notifications, pi)`.

Comment: I wanted to mention. that I tried you code and it works FANTASTIC!!!  since it is now working in my app with no errors. I will study the code more in detail now so I can understand how it works.  Thank you for your help

Comment: Don't you need to register this receiver in the Manifest?